# Reading a 32-bit ADC result with a 16-bit SPI interface

Tags: signal-processing, adc

I need to measure a very small ripple on a power supply output that represents about `0.0017%` of the output voltage. As a result, I need high-resolution ADC to do this. I am using the `F2837xD` board which has at most 12-bits of resolution for single-ended signals, and because of the differential mode configuration I cannot use the 16-bit differential ADCs, and even if I could, not all the bits would be usable and the resolution still isn't good enough.

I plan to use an external ADC with at least 20-bits of resolution and to communicate with the SPI interface that is on the board. The issue is that the maximum word length of the SPI register is 16-bits.

Is there a way to read 20-bits or more accurately with a 16-bit SPI interface, whether this be in software or any additional hardware that could be utilized after the external ADC? How much of the accuracy gained from using an external high-resolution ADC would actually be retained in these circumstances?

https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruhm8i/spruhm8i.pdf?ts=1631716470368&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Ftool%252FTMDSDOCK28379D%253FkeyMatch%253DTMDSDOCK28379D on page 2223 for the SPI interface.

Comment: dont necessarily need high res.  if psu is going to be at a set voltage and delta off that is what you care about, use ac coupling to discard the dc flat voltage.  you can also use an op amp to scale the voltage to the range you want- as long as the ripple itself fits.

Comment: for high res over spi, read two or more words and then bitshidt and combine if you really need to.  You'll mostly be subtracting anyway so you can also just do the subtraction on 16-bit.

Comment: The ripple is certainly more important than the actual set DC voltage, but they are both important in their own right. I'll have a look into AC coupling. With regards to the operations for the high resolution solution, why would this be subtraction? I had though multiplying 16-bit by 16-bit would give a 32-bit result, not subtraction. The issue is that the SPI input to the DSP allows 16-bit word to be read maximum, and I'm not sure whether it supports shifting. Maybe I could use GPIO's instead. Need to spend today digging into the data sheet.

Comment: subtraction to find the "ripple"  If you do most significant 16-bit minus most significant and least minus least, you can combine them to 32-bit after if necessary.  bit shift and 32-bit are implemented by the compiler for whatever your processor is.  if processor is 16-bit for example, doing 32-bit math is possible but multiple 16-bit computations.